# CQRS/Event sourcing and MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, design-patterns, prism

I have an application built with WPF and PRISM.
This is a large project, and is event driven.

Logging is really important, so I was looking at incorporating CQRS and Event sourcing principles so we can log more, and better.

We also have some 'state' like displaying and setting the computername.

Now I am trying to wrap my head around a couple things:

1. Things that are not event-based like the computer name (Which would not be in my control/database)
   How would I read and set the value?
2. Some dataflow will come from the UI, thus being a command. Some will also come from external systems (lets say I poll a server and have a 'changed' event)
   How would this work? would I need to generate a Command or inject in directly into the event store?
3. How would this work with MVVM?
   Would I need to get rid of MVVM - or should i use these patterns in conjunction etc.

Note: The main goal is logging - although replaying and all other pro's event sourcing provides would be handy too.

Also - some examples/sources tackling a broaders spectrum would be helpfull.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's pretty unclear to me.

1) What has obtaining a computer name got to do with CQRS or EventSourcing?  2) If the fulfilment of an event requires the collection of additional data, then the implementation of the event must incorporate the method for obtaining those data. 3) CQRS and EventSourcing have nothing to do with MVVM. `MVVM` is concerned with separating a data model from the visualisation of that model. CQRS and EventSourcing are related to two completely unrelated concepts; reading and writing data to a data store, and ii running a system on events

Comment: Hello thanks for you reply!
1) My app receives data from a server. But besides handling this data I also query other data like the computer name, or perhaps i read configdata from a file, edit an .csv file. How would an event based approach deal with these situations where parts of the app aren't really event-driven.
2) check!
3) My app currently uses MVVM to seperate model and UI. Now i have Debug.Logs everywhere - and not that consistent. I am thinking about applying eventsourcing somehow so that logging happens automatically (I simply subscribe a logger to all events)

Comment: I'm not certain that you fully appreciate what EventSourcing is. This term does not mean _a UI that is EventDriven_, but rather it means that the business logic is a series of events: for example, a BankAccount is maintained through EventSourcing, i.e, the Account balance is never modified directly, but rather a series of events take place on the Account to bring us to a current balance: 1) 0.00 Account Opened 2) 200 deposited 3) 15.98 paid out 4) 1000 paid in … then the balance can be calculated. This means that the full history of the account can be replayed to come to the same balance.

Comment: if there are "extra" data required then they need to be included as part of the stored event, otherwise the result will possibly (and most likely) be different each time you replay the events. A system using `Event Sourcing` must be composed of discrete idempotent services/operations. In the Bank Account example above, the Balance is not calculated and stored after each event, but rather the events are stored and replayed in order to calculate the Balance as required: a strategy has been put in place to maybe cache the balance at the end of each day so that not  ALL events need replaying daily

Comment: however, if all of the events were to be replayed, the end result would ALWAYS be the same

Comment: Thanks again, that clears some matters up. However in the bank analogy, how would one go about incorporating the display of data out of an external service? Lets say i deposit 100,- to a bitcoin account. A command gets sent, an event gets raised. Now when I want to display my bitcoin account balance, i get all events and calculate the amount. However - since it is an external service, the bitcoin account may be altered - and the returned bitcount balance would not reflect the changes in the external service. I'd have to request the state of the external service's bitcoin account balance again.

Comment: Also - lets say a variable gets updated and an event gets raised. The UI should respond to this change. Would i sent the event to the ViewModel in MVVM, or straight to the View to process and show the event? Or perhaps have this event only update the model. How would one go about this?

Comment: Again, this is not Event Sourcing, this is just Event Driven UI. Your View should be bound to a ViewModel, and when data change within the ViewModel the UI is updated through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You should change the title of the question and reword it because this has nothing to do with `EventSourcing` or `CQRS`